# is there a gis web engine for displaying video on terrain?

Tags: software-recommendations, terrain, video, worldwind

i desire to display video on a globe surface on it's geographic position context.

i prefer an opensource solution for displaying the video on map elevation model in web GIS application, but could not found any example for this need.

i found a java-client application based on Worldwind GIS engine for video on terrain at http://goworldwind.org/demos/.

but did not found any web-based example.

Comment: I remember see a Silverlight map tutorial on a style called VideoBrush. But can't find it ....

Comment: On which map engine?

Comment: It was an old virtual earth app: http://soulsolutions.com.au/2009/04/05/

Comment: Do you know pure js solution?